# First steps with htlatex, I'm losing all the math format!

Tags: html, pandoc, htlatex, mathjax, latex2html

I'm doing my first steps with htlatex, trying to get HTML documents. I have OS: Linux Mint, Tex Live, and I make my *.tex with Texmaker. I know how to use MathJax.
I get this:

[image: After running htlatex]

This is how I wish it should look!

[image: How it should look!]

So I managed this with Pandoc, I simply did like this:
       `$ pandoc -s -o *.html -f latex -t html5 --mathjax *.tex`

The only thing I'd learn is how to insert '\require{cancel}', then I've finished.

Comment: could you please provide a `mwe` and also exact command you use for compilation?

Comment: Do you mean "minimal working example"? Well, my first time so I did directly ">htlatex *.tex". I couldn't find more info on htlatex.
I did try Pandoc, worked fantastic! @Harry

Comment: yes. I mean "minimal working example". it you get that result with default settings, you probably have some problem with your setup, because math is converted to images by default. you can find some documentation for `tex4ht` [here](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) and [here](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you Cristian! If you're happy with the answer please do vote up/accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) for converting LaTeX to HTML with good math support.

From the front page:

> Several different methods of rendering math in HTML are provided, including MathJax and translation to MathML.

Also, check out [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) for very nice (pretty much 1:1) conversion of PDF output to HTML.